# iterate a list from second element to last element

Tags: python

I wish to iterate my list from the second to last element. If possible I wish to have both answers for using my current codes with little alteration and also a new and better code.

```
integer = [1,3,2,4]
for i in range(len(integer)):
    #for ii in range(i+1%len(integer)):
    print(integer[(i+1)%len(integer)])
```

Current output:

```
3
2
4
1
```

Expected output:

```
3
2
4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **The range() function**
>
> We can generate a sequence of numbers using range() function.
> range(10) will generate numbers from 0 to 9 (10 numbers).
> We can also define the **start, stop and step size** as `range(start,stop,step size)`. step size defaults to 1 if not
> provided.
> This function does not store all the values in memory, it would be inefficient. So it remembers the start, stop, step size and
> generates the next number on the go.

Your code should looks like:

```
integer = [1,3,2,4]
for i in range(1,len(integer)):
    print (integer[i])
```

Output:

```
3
2
4
```

Answer (score 6):

There is actually no need to use indices here, as Python loops allow to iterate over elements directly. Then, with simple list slicing you can take the range you want:

```py
integers = [1,3,2,4]
for integer in integers[1:]:
    print(integer)
```

Or, to iterate over elements instead of indexes, but avoid creating a new copy of the list (slices create a new list object), you can use [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```py
from itertools import islice

for integer in islice(integers, 1, None):
    print(integer)
```

Comment: I like your solution (list[1:]) because it works with a list of strings, range doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

For your current code with minimal changes you can do:

```
integer = [1,3,2,4]
for i in range(len(integer[1:])):
    print(integer[i])
```

You can write it as such instead:

```
l = [1,2,3,4]
for i, e in enumerate(l[1:]):
    # i is the index, e is the actual element
    print(e)
```

Comment: But this copies the list, not so memory efficient

Comment: why use `enumerate` if you're intending to use `i`?

Comment: just wanted to show that there's a way to get both the index and element at the same time from the iterable

Comment: By the way the `range` solution is not good. You are iterating from first to one before last, not second to last. `for i in range(...)` will still start at 0 so it doesn't give the expected output

Answer (score 2):

`range` takes `(start,end,step)` as parameters.
You can therefore write `for i in range(1,len(integer))`

Answer (score 2):

You can simply slice the list.

```
for i in integer[1:]:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Reduce the Index range and shift the index when accessing elements:

```
 for i in range(len(integer) - 1):     
     print(integer[i+1])
```

It's easier using the 2-parameter form:

```
 for i in range(1, len(integer)):     
     print(integer[i])
```